# Show that $(A\cap A')\setminus (B\cap B')=(A\setminus B)\cap (A'\setminus B')$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $$(A\cap A')\setminus (B\cap B')=(A\setminus B)\cap (A'\setminus B')$$ for arbitrary sets $A,B,A',B'$.

I have done the following:

Let $x\in (A\cap A')\setminus (B\cap B')$.

Then we have that
\begin{align*}x\in &(A\cap A')\setminus (B\cap B') \iff x\in (A\cap A') \land x\notin  (B\cap B') \\ &\iff ((x\in A)\land (x\in A')) \land x\in  (B\cap B')^c \\ &\iff ((x\in A)\land (x\in A')) \land x\in  (B^c\cup B'^c) \\ &\iff ((x\in A)\land (x\in A')) \land   ((x\in B^c)\lor (x\in B'^c)) \\ &\iff ((x\in A)\land (x\in A')\land (x\in B^c))    \lor ((x\in A)\land (x\in A') \land (x\in B'^c)) \end{align*}

Is everything correct so far? How could we continue?

Comment: By any chance, did you mean $(A \cap A') \setminus (B \cup B')$ instead of $(A \cap A') \setminus (B \cap B')$?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the equality that you mentioned

$$(A\cap A')\setminus (B\cap B')=(A\setminus B)\cap (A'\setminus B') \tag{1}$$

is not true, in general.

Consider the following.

$$\begin{align}
x \in (A \cap A’) \setminus (B \cap B’) & \iff x \in A \cap A’ \wedge x \notin B \cap B’\\
& \iff \big(x \in A \wedge x \in A’\big) \wedge \big( x \notin B \vee x \notin B’ \big)\\
& \iff \big( x \in A \wedge x \in A’ \wedge x \notin B \big)\\
& \quad \quad \quad \vee \big(x \in A \wedge x \in A’ \wedge x \notin B’\big)\\
& \implies \big( x \in A \wedge x \notin B \big) \vee \big( x \in A’ \wedge x \notin B’ \big)\\
& \iff (x \in A \setminus B) \vee \big( x \in A’ \setminus B’ \big)\\
& \iff x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (A’ \setminus B’)
\end{align}$$

From this I can just get a counter example that shows that $(1)$ doesn’t hold.

$$A = \{1,2\} \quad A’ = \{1\} \quad B = \{1\} \quad B’ = \{2\}$$

$$\begin{align}
1 \in A,A’,B \wedge 1 \notin B’ & \implies 1 \in A \cap A’ \wedge 1 \notin B \cap B’\\
& \implies 1 \in (A \cap A’) \setminus (B \cap B’)
\end{align}$$

$$1 \in A,B \implies 1 \notin A \setminus B \implies 1 \notin (A\setminus B) \cap (A’ \setminus B’)$$

Comment: $A'$ must never contain $1$ because it is already an element of $A$.

Comment: @manooooh I’m defining the set $A’ = \{1\}.$

Comment: Oh, sorry, typically $'$ denotes complement of a set. If you want you can edit your answer to remove my downvote. Thanks!

Comment: @manooooh no problem, in fact it was an unfortunate choose of notation. I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A correct formula would be the following:
$$ (A\smallsetminus B)\cap(A'\smallsetminus B')=(A\cap A')\smallsetminus(B\cup B'), $$
which is easy to prove:
\begin{align}
(A\smallsetminus B)\cap(A'\smallsetminus B')&=(A\cap B^c)\cap(A'\cap B'^c) \\
&=(A\cap A')\cap (B^c\cap B'^c)\\
&=(A\cap A')\cap (B\cup B')^c=(A\cap A')\smallsetminus(B\cup B').
\end{align}

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Oh! yes. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Do more........

Comment: Bis repetita placent … ;o)